Need to Fix: Call to a member function real_escape_string()
I've created a login/register system in php, however I am receiving the call to member error, and Im unsure on how to fix it? I am simply trying to check that the password the user inputted into signup.php is the same as the hashed and original password in signup_user.php.
Here is my code:
sigin.php

<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
ini_set("display_startup_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$is_invalid = false;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {

    $mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/connection.php";

    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE user_name = '%s'",
            # prevent sql injection(below)
            $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["Username"]));

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if ($user) {

       if (password_verify($_POST["Password"], $user["password_hash"])) {

        session_start();

        session_regenerate_id();

        $_SESSION["id"] = $user["user_id"];
        echo "Successful Login :) ... redirecting";
        exit;
       }
    }

    $is_invalid = true;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login to your account</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Courgette|Pacifico:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signin.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="signin-form">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-header">
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <p>Login to MyChat</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" autocomplete="off" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="Password" autocomplete="off" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="small">Forgot password? <a href="forgot_pass.php">Click Here</a></div><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" name="sign_in">Sign in</button>
        </div>
        <?php #include("signin_user.php"); ?>   
    </form>
    <div class="text-center small" style='color:#67428B;'>Don't have an account? <a href="signup.php">Create one</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>    

connection.php

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecom") or die("Connection was not established");
?>

signup_user.php

<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
ini_set("display_startup_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);


#include("/connection.php");
include("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Ecom/chat/code/connection.php");


    if(isset($_POST['sign_up'])){
        
    # password hash:

    $password = $_POST['user_pass'];
    $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_user_pass'];
    $pin = $_POST['user_pin'];
    $confirm_pin = $_POST['confirm_user_pin'];
    
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $confirm_password_hash = password_hash($confirm_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $pin_hash = password_hash($pin, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $confirm_pin_hash = password_hash($confirm_pin, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    
    # pass hash data & POST data to db:

    $name = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_name']));
    $pass = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password_hash));
    $confirm_pass = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$confirm_password_hash));
    $pin = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$pin_hash));
    $confirm_pin = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$confirm_pin_hash));
    $rand = rand(1, 3); //Random number between 1 and 3

    # Register Validation
    if(empty($name)){
        echo "<script>alert('Username is required')</script>";
    }
    if(strlen($name) < 3) {
        echo "<script>alert('Username must be 3 - 30 characters')</script>";
        exit();
    }elseif(strlen($name) > 30) {
        echo "<script>alert('Username must be 3 - 30 characters')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['user_pass'])<12){
        echo "<script>alert('Password must be at least 12 characters')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if(! preg_match("/[A-Z]/i", $_POST["user_pass"])){
        echo "<script>alert('Password must contain at least one capital letter')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if (! preg_match("/[0-9]/", $_POST["user_pass"])) {
        echo "<script>alert('Password must contain at least one number')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if (! preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", $_POST["user_pass"])) {
        echo "<script>alert('Password must contain at least one symbol')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if ($_POST["user_pass"] !== $_POST["confirm_user_pass"]) {
        echo "<script>alert('Password must match')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if (! is_numeric($_POST["user_pin"])) {
        echo "<script>alert('Pin must contain numbers only')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    if ($_POST["user_pin"] !== $_POST["confirm_user_pin"]) {
        echo "<script>alert('Pin must match')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    # Check for duplicate Username
    $check_username = "select * from users where user_name='$name'";
    $run_username = mysqli_query($con,$check_username);

    $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_username);

    if($check==1){

    echo "<script>alert('Username already exist, please try another!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('signup.php','_self')</script>";
    exit();
    }
    }   

    # Pass php variable into sql db
    $insert = "insert into users (user_name,
                                user_pass,
                                confirm_user_pass,
                                user_pin,
                                confirm_user_pin)
                values ('$name',
                        '$pass',
                        '$confirm_pass',
                        '$pin',
                        '$confirm_pin')";

    $query = mysqli_query($con,$insert);

    # Register confirmation
    if($query){
    echo "<script>alert('Congratulations $name, your account has been created successfully.')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('signin.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
    echo "<script>alert('Registration failed, try again!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('signup.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}
?>


Does this answer your question? Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object

Your connection variable is clearly called $con, not $mysqli. Look at your connection file, and looks at how you used the connection in your second script. And you might also want to read the manual and check what require actually returns.

@ADyson I've tried to use $con, and also changed "require" to "include", but still returning the same error.

You don't need to change require to include, not sure what gave you that impression. But remove the assignment from before the start of require

P.S. mysqli_real_escape_string is obsolete, and has been for 20 years - not sure where you were taught to use that. It can protect against some SQL injection and related problems, but not all. You should learn the right techniques: You must use prepared statements and parameters to make your queries secure and reliable. You can find explanation and examples of that in many places, including How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

And why are you storing the password and pin twice in the database?? That makes no sense. You only need one copy of each. The confirmation fields for those should just be checked before inserting, to validate that the user wrote what they intended to. You don't need to store the main field and the confirmation field, because they should be identical!

And your use of htmlentities is inappropriate. This is an output filter, to prevent XSS attacks in a HTML document. It's only relevant to use it when you're about to put the data into a HTML document (e.g. when outputting it on your web page). Storing your data already HTML-encoded in the database isn't a good idea - what if you need to use that data in a non-HTML environment at some point??

And HTML-encoding a password  makes even less sense - a user's password should never get shown on a web page, for one thing, and for another thing what if I want to use, for example < or > in my password? Any reason I shouldn't do that? But if I do, your code will mangle it and store something completely different in the database, without my knowledge!! Might make it a bit tricky to log in, after you've done that...

See info such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592702/when-to-use-strip-tags-and-when-to-use-htmlspecialchars and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882307/when-to-use-htmlspecialchars-function for info on when to use htmlentities and htmlspecialchars (their functionality is similar enough that the same advice applies to both). N.B. These functions certainly have nothing to do with SQL  injection, in case you are labouring under that common misunderstanding.

Writing a signup & login system successfully really isn't a sensible topic for an inexperienced programmer, or one unfamiliar with security on the web - there are so many ways to make a complete mess of it, some of which are demonstrated in your attempt (as I've alluded to). Far better IMHO to use a ready-made, expert-written module or framework which provides such functionality, fully tested, out of the box, and concentrate your energies on making new and interesting functionality for your website, while learning more about PHP and so on as you go.
